# data grid binding in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, gridview

I have a simple class abc

```
class abc
        {
            public string a { get; set; }
            public string b { get; set; }
            public string c { get; set; }

            public abc(string d, string e, string f)
            {
                a = d;
                b = e;
                c = f;
            }
        }



public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            abc obj = new abc("abc1", "abc2", "abc3");
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = obj;


        }
```

and a grid which contain three textbox 1 2 3 I am trying to bind these 3 properties of a class to a grid usercontrol.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,86,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path= a}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,192,0,83" Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Path= b}"  Width="120" />
        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,192,0,0" Name="textBox3" Text="{Binding Path= c}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="120" />
    </Grid>
```

it doesn't show any error but it does not show any output to a screen,what specific problem it creating?

Comment: Layoutroo is the name of my grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do not use "Path= " (with space) in the binding expression. Try use:

```
Text="{Binding a}"
```

"Path" is present hiddenly in binding expressions. You need read some resources about bindings.

Answer (score 0):

First your type 'abc' should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class abc : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```

Then you need to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.PropertyChanged event

```
private void RaiseProperty(string propertyName)
{
    var handle = PropertyChanged;
    if(handle != null)
    {
        handle(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private string _a;
public string a { get{ return _a;} set{ _a = value; RaiseProperty("a"); } }

....
```

This should work as you need to a mechanism to notify the Binding if you are using CLR proprties; and that mechanism is provided by `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

Comment: Is that needed in the example above?

Comment: thanks sir. as i am new to silverlight. i am just working on this next.

Comment: In general you would implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but it's not required above and not the cause of the problem.

Comment: agreed to Preet Sangha and Phil. The only problem is the type is not public.